# How do I get the X and Y position of a div relative to the div it is appended to and not the viewport in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, position

I need to find the X and Y position of a div within another div, and not relative to the viewport like getboundingclient() returns. Is there a way to do this?

[Position Relative to the Parent Div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BR6YC.png)

Comment: Regardless of whether or not the div it is appended to is relative, wouldn't the x/y coordinates be the same?

Comment: You get coordinates for both of the parent and child, then substract the parent's coordinates with child's coordinates.

Comment: @HaoWu Yes, this is what I originally was thinking of doing, but I figured there might be some method like offset mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's just a matter of math.

When you have X and Y from both elements, your element you want to know the coordinates for and its wrapping container, then you only have to subtract the `element - container` coordinates.

Note: This also works if the element is not an immediate children of the container.

See the example below, where blue is the wrapping container and red is the element you want to know the coordinates from *inside* the blue container.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const element = document.querySelector('.element');

// get the domrect for your targeted container
const containerDomrect = container.getBoundingClientRect();

// get the domrect for you relement you wanna have the x/y coordinates
const elementDomrect = element.getBoundingClientRect();

// then simply subtract the x/y values of the container from the element
const xCoord = elementDomrect.x - containerDomrect.x;
const yCoord = elementDomrect.y - containerDomrect.y;

console.log('X coordinate: ' + xCoord);
console.log('Y coordinate: ' + yCoord);
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
}

.element {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```